# Convert Maybe Int to Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working on the following code and wanted to find the index of the number in the box string. So I used `findIndex` but it returns the `Maybe Int` value whereas I want only `Int` value.

How can I convert `Maybe Int` to `Int` value or is there any way in which I can extract `Int` from `Maybe Int`. The code should print an error message if `Maybe Int` is `Nothing`.

```
box:: String
box = unlines $ ["0 | 1 | 2",
                 "---------",
                 "3 | 4 | 5",
                 "---------",
                 "6 | 7 | 8"]

moves = do
        putStrLn " Enter the number"
        number <- readLn :: IO Int
        print number
        findpostion number box

findposition number box = findIndex (==number) box
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can easily do this using pattern matching in your `do` statement:

```
case findposition number box of
  Just n  -> -- do whatever with n
  Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid number!" -- you can handle the error however you want.
```

A good option would be to create a separate IO action to get the number:

```
getNumber = do putStrLn "Enter the number:"
               number <- readLn
               case findposition number box of
                 Just n  -> -- Do whatever
                 Nothing -> putStrLn "Please try again." >> getNumber
```

This way if the user enters an invalid number, it just asks again.

Also, as written now, your code won't work. You should have some other way of storing the numbers in `box` as actual numbers; right now, they're in Strings.

Comment: Actually the intention was to find the number entered by user and  replace it later on with any other character say 'x'

Comment: Ah. In that case, since you're looking through a String, you'll want to read in a `Char` rather than an `Int`. In fact, you should be able to leave out the `:: IO Int` bit entirely.

Answer (score 12):

Obviously, it's not possible in general: when the search doesn't succeed there is no canonical integer return value, so you get a `Nothing` without any such value then.

If you don't really care about the `Nothing` case (e.g. because you will always make sure there is one such element) you can use the `fromJust` function out of `Data.Maybe`, which you can also quickly implement yourself:

```
findposition number = (\(Just i)->i) . findIndex (==number)
```

However that's not really recommendable because you *will* need to make sure this doesn't break, and doing this is much easier by means of a proper pattern matching.

Comment: He mentioned that he wanted to "return an error message" on `Nothing`. While this is a little ambiguous, I assumed he'd be happy just printing the error out rather than having his program crash.

Comment: If there *is* a "canonical integer" for the context in which you are working, you can use `fromMaybe canonicalInt maybeVal` where `canonicalInt :: Int` and `maybeVal :: Maybe Int`. See [Data.Maybe docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe)