# convert maybe int to int in a complex function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have such a function:

```
to_ref :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Mat El -> Mat El
to_ref cb ce rb re m
     | cb <= ce && (find_non_null_row cb rb re m) == Nothing = (to_ref (cb+1) ce rb re m)
     | cb <= ce && (find_non_null_row cb rb re m) /= Nothing = (elim_all cb rb re (find_non_null_row cb rb re m) m) : (to_ref (cb+1) ce rb re m)
     | otherwise = m
```

In `(elim_all cb rb re (find_non_null_row cb rb re m) m) : (to_ref (cb+1) ce rb re m)`, `(find_non_null_row cb rb re m)` returns a `Maybe Int` type value, but I need it as `Int` type to make my code work.

I have checked this post, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905272/convert-maybe-int-to-int-in-haskell`, but I couldn't fit the solution to my issue.

How can I convert it to `Int` in the most efficient way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Maybe Int to Int in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905272/convert-maybe-int-to-int-in-haskell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use pattern matching. Here, I invert the comparison of `cb` and `ce` to get that out of the way for the more complicated case.

```
to_ref cb ce _ _ m | cb > ce = m
-- If we get to this case, we know cb < ce
to_ref cb ce rb re m = let ref = to_ref (cb+1) ce rb re m
                           row = find_non_null_row cb rb re m
                       in case row of
                           Nothing -> ref
                           Just x -> elim_all cb rb re x m : ref
```

You can also use the `maybe` function if you don't like the `case` expression.

```
to_ref cb ce rb re m = let ref = to_ref (cb+1) ce rb re m
                           row_f x = elim_all cb rb re x m : ref
                           row = find_non_null_row cb rb re m
                       in maybe ref row_f row
```

Comment: Prelude.!!: index too large

Comment: Given that `!!` doesn't appear in this code at all, I have very few ideas about what to do. Is it possible that your original code should have been using `cb < ce` as a condition, meaning I would use `cb >= ce` for the base case?

Answer (score 1):

My style would be to use `PatternGuards`.

```
to_ref :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Mat El -> Mat El
to_ref cb ce rb re m
     | cb <= ce, Just row <- find_non_null_row cb rb re m 
         = elim_all cb rb re row m : to_ref (cb+1) ce rb re m
     | cb <= ce 
         = to_ref (cb+1) ce rb re m
     | otherwise = m
```

List comprehensions actually seem to fit quite well

```
to_ref cb0 ce rb re m = newItems ++ m
   where 
   newItems = [ elim_all cb rb re row m 
              | cb <- [cb0..ce]
              , Just row <- find_non_null_row cb rb re m
              ]
```

assuming I did that refactor right...

Answer (score 1):

The three guards you're currently using could be separated into two guards and a case expression (to unwrap the `Maybe`). I've also abstracted away some of the repeated computations with a `let`

```
to_ref :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Mat El -> Mat El
to_ref cb ce rb re m
    | cb <= ce =
        let
            ref = to_ref (cb + 1) ce rb re m
            row = find_non_null_row cb rb re m
        in case row of
            Nothing -> ref
            Just x -> elim_all cb rb re x m : ref
    | otherwise = m
```